# Organizing an XML result list with C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, api, xamarin.forms

I am having a problem on how to organize my list of food that is a result of a endpoint I have created.
Here is the problem:

This is my class `Food`...as you can see it has a list of `Nutrient`s that I will need for later.

```
public class Food
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FoodID { get; set; }
    public string FoodName { get; set; }
    public List <Nutrient> Nutrients { get; set; }
}

public class Nutrient
{
    public string NutrientName { get; set; }
    public decimal NutrientValue { get; set; }
}
```

This is my current XML that is returned:

```xml
<Food>
<FoodID>9003</FoodID>
<FoodName>Apples, raw, with skin</FoodName>
<ID>0</ID>
<Nutrient>Protein</Nutrient>
<NutrientValue>0.260</NutrientValue>
</Food>

<Food>
<FoodID>9003</FoodID>
<FoodName>Apples, raw, with skin</FoodName>
<ID>0</ID>
<Nutrient>Total lipid (fat)</Nutrient>
<NutrientValue>0.170</NutrientValue>
</Food>

<Food>
<FoodID>9003</FoodID>
<FoodName>Apples, raw, with skin</FoodName>
<ID>0</ID>
<Nutrient>Carbohydrate</Nutrient>
<NutrientValue>13.810</NutrientValue>
</Food>
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```xml
<Food>
<FoodID>9003</FoodID>
<FoodName>Apples, raw, with skin</FoodName>
<ID>0</ID>
<Nutrient>
<NutrientName>Protein</Nutrient>
<NutrientValue>0.260</NutrientValue>
<NutrientName>Total lipid (fat)</Nutrient>
<NutrientValue>0.170</NutrientValue>
<NutrientName>Carbohydrate</Nutrient>
<NutrientValue>13.810</NutrientValue>
</Nutrient>
</Food>
```

Basically, I want to order a list by ID and so the nutrients that belong to the same `FoodID` stay together in a list.

Any idea how I can achieve this result?

Comment: do you control the API that is returning the json?

Comment: @Jason yes i do!

Comment: You could create an element named Nutrient and add name and value attributes to it, like this: <Nutrient name="Protein" value="0.26" />. Then element Food would contain a collection of Nutrients.

Comment: Can you share the code for that endpoint? I would also advise to use a Nutrient ID or create an enumeration with all the nutrients.

Answer (score 0):

When you must rely on DataContract serialization (WCF), you could do something like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Food
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name ="Nutrients")]
    public List<Nutrient> Nutrients { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "Nutrient")]
public class Nutrient
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Value")]
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

This should give you an XML like this:

```
<Food>
  <Id>9003</Id>
  <Name>Apples, raw with skin</Name>
  <Nutrients>
    <Nutrient>
      <Name>Protein</Name>
      <Value>0.260</Value>
    </Nutrient>
    <Nutrient>
      <Name>Total lipid (fat)</Name>
      <Value>0.170</Value>
    </Nutrient>
    <Nutrient>
      <Name>Carbohydrate</Name>
      <Value>13.810</Value>
    </Nutrient>
  </Nutrients>
</Food>
```

Note: with data contract serialization you cannot use XML attributes. Basically it should be pretty plain XML with all elements placed in a fixed order.